# Phaser useHandCursor is not working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to debug a case where all sprites that have the hand cursor turned on do not actually display them properly.

- When you hover, the cursor does not change
- When you click down, the hand cursor still fires.
- Down events still fire but I *think* over/out events are not firing
- There are no errors/warnings for the game in the console.
- Same thing happens in a few browsers

Since this project is a derivative of another project where the cursor works, I'm trying to slowly step back my code but not really having luck so far with that. So trying to drum up ideas on how to figure this out.

---

**Edit**

Since this happened again, on another project I thought I would post up code. I boiled this down to a very simple game and it still happens. This is with Phaser 2.4.8 and Pixi v2.2.9.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #000;
      }
      canvas {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="./assets/js/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var game = new Phaser.Game(2280, 1440, Phaser.CANVAS, '', {
      preload: function() {
        game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
        game.load.spritesheet('help', 'assets/img/help-button.png', 130, 130);
      },
      create: function() {
        var help = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'help', 0);
        help.inputEnabled = true;
        help.input.useHandCursor = true;
      }
    });

    function resizeGame() {
      this.scale.refresh();
    }

    window.onresize = resizeGame.bind(game);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="game"></div>
    <audio id="audio" controls style="display:none">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what version of phaser are you using? also code snippets?

Comment: I was able to rebuild from the previous game and it worked again. I'm really unsure why it stopped working in the first place. Not sure if I should just kill this question or what.

Comment: Since this happened again, I am adding an example.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work with 2.4.8? (Does work with 2.4.7) https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/2507